# Controller method using old response from service promise after first time in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function inside my controller:

```
function getNewNotifications() {
    NotificationService.getNotifications('new')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("in controller: ", response.results);
            vm.notificationCount = response.count;
        },function (err) {
            console.log(err);
    });
}
```

here is the `getNotifications` method of `NotificationService`:

```
function getNotifications(status) {
        var thisUrl = url + '?status=' + status;

        $http.get(thisUrl)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log("in service: ", data.results);
                deferer.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                deferer.reject(data);
            });

        return deferer.promise;
    }
```

Both of them log results in their success methods.

I call the controller function like this:

```
setInterval(getNewNotifications, 5000);
```

i.e. it gets new notifications every five seconds!

The first time the controller method is called, the browser logs are:

```
in service: Object
in controller: Object
```

As expected! However, after this, the order is reversed:

```
in controller: Object
in service: Object
```

This is weird and leading to other problems.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Where is `deferer` created? It needs to be recreated each time `getNotifications` is called. Note however that `http.get` already returns a promise, you might not even need to create a promise manually yourself.

Comment: @tasseKATT exactly! I created `deferer` globally inside a service thinking that it does not matter! If you please write it as an answer, I will accept it! Thank you very much

Comment: Will do. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the promise is created outside the `getNotifications` function it will already be resolved the second time the function is called, and the data from the first call will be returned again.

You simply need to recreate a new promise each time `getNotifications` is called.